# Models shared among applications : DataMapper Rails Other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datamapper

I have a set of models I need to share among several rails3/sinatra/etc applications. I haven't seen anything like this yet and I'm curious what is the most effective way to go about this in a DRY manner? Can I specify a central area for models, can I create a gem that only brings in the models I need? How have other people approached this issue. I was thinking of making a smallish gem or something I don't yet know about to handle this.

I'm using Datamapper, but this is also a more general issue of structuring multiple rails/non rails ruby apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find it's easier to have a submodule in your repository that contains your models and associated unit tests than to create a full-fledged gem. This way you can patch from one app to the other instead of having to drive everything top down.

Comment: This is the first step I'll need to take.

Answer (score 0):

You can create public API to models you want to use in other apps.

In rails you should already have REST controllers, so you can use ActiveResource in the other apps.

You can pack your ActiveResource classes in a gem just to simplify thing and to keep things DRY.

You can check: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html for some examples.

And it doesn't matter if you're using ActiveRecord or DataMapper.

Comment: This is interesting and I can see its use. I'll need to delve deeper to find out how to implement something like this hmm like an api on the db server maybe.